# React - Show different value in input box based on the state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Problem Question - I have a form. The form has a state of editable and non-editable, which makes the input box to edit. Now this particular input box has to show different value depending upon what state it is in. i.e if it is not in editable state it has to show '27 November 2016' and if editable state it has to show '27/11/2016'.

The problem is when i try to edit this input box, therefore remove the pre defined value '27/11/2016' it does not work. I think it is not possible to bind function with value.

What I tried -

```
function showDate() {
  if(!this.props.isEdit){
     return longDate();
  }
     return shortDate();
}

 <input 
    id='test'
    value={this.showDate()}
    onChange={this.props.onInputChange}
    readOnly={!this.props.isEdit}             
  />
```

Can someone please suggest on this?

Update: I have a Component which has function `onInputChange` and all i want to show different content inside input box when the form is in edit mode.

Comment: You're going to need to share the rest of your code, including `onInputChange` for some context

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more what you are trying to do? Here's a basic jsfiddle I made to try to reproduce your case: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: I have update the question

Answer (score 0):

you should use `state` instead of `props` for input change, something like below

```
function onInputChange() {
  if(!this.props.isEdit){
     this.setState({
         date: longDate()
     });
     return;
  }

  this.setState({
      date: shorDate()
  });
}


 <input 
    id='test'
    value={this.state.date}
    onChange={onInputChange}
    readOnly={!this.props.isEdit}             
  />
```